# Update tkinter slider value in for loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using the tkinter slider widget to take input value from the user, which I'm using inside the `for` loop.  How do I update the slider value inside the code dynamically, that is, as the user changes the slider value the `for` loop range must also be changed accordingly.

```
def get_current_value1():
    return int('{}'.format(current_value1.get()))

def slider_changed1(event):
    value_label1.configure(text=get_current_value1())

for i in range(get_current_value1()):
    minus_Matrix = dilate(minus_Matrix, kernel_d)
        
for i in range(get_current_value2()):
    minus_Matrix = erode(minus_Matrix, kernel_e)
```

[Project Link](https://github.com/Surveillance-NWB/Surveillance/blob/main/Surveillance.NWB.py)

Comment: First of all, why are you using: `int('{}'.format(current_value1.get()))` instead of `current_value1.get()`? Second of all, please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: In your code as posted, the two `for` loops run exactly one time, before the user has had any chance to adjust the slider.  You would need to put them in a function, and call that function every time the value changes - from inside `slider_changed1()`, for example.

Comment: Don't post links to code hosted on offsite locations since they are likely to eventually disappear.